# I am creating an attendance app where i want to restrict employess from specific location to deny attendance service

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, geocoding

For this I am using geolocator and geocoding packages from Flutter.
I dont know how to deny permission for specific address or location with name or latitude and longitude

This is my code for Attendance register app

```
  Future<void> _getCurrentPosition() async {
    final hasPermission = await _handleLocationPermission();

    if (!hasPermission) return;
    await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() => _currentPosition = position);
      _getAddressFromLatLng(_currentPosition!);
    }).catchError((e) {
      debugPrint(e);
    });
  }

  Future<void> _getAddressFromLatLng(Position position) async {
    await placemarkFromCoordinates(
            _currentPosition!.latitude, _currentPosition!.longitude)
        .then((List<Placemark> placemarks) {
      Placemark place = placemarks[0];
      setState(() {
        _currentAddress =
            '${place.street}, ${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode}';
      });
      addAttendanceToDatabase();
    }).catchError((e) {
      debugPrint(e);
    });
  }
```

*In the current location i need to deny permission if it is within the specific latitude and longitude

Also I need to show Snackbar message like 

**You cant put attendance inside the office address***

Here is my Pubspec code for loaction access

```
geolocator: ^9.0.2
  geocoding: ^2.1.0
```

Comment: What do you mean by restrict? What is the desired outcome? Your "question" is way to broad. You need to specify your problem in much more detail.

Comment: Restrict means i want the employee should not put attendance inside the office like that

Comment: So, with the office address i want them to restrict from putting attendance

Comment: What do you mean "like that" ? Still doesn't make any sense. , and you have entered way to much code. Only present the minimal amount of code to reproduce an error. Specificy current behavior, and specify the  desired behavior, preferably with examples. Update the question. Don't add a bunch of extra comments.

Comment: I have cleared and specified my issue it that ok

Comment: Please do not abuse formatting to make everything in your post bold. All that does is make your post harder to read.

Comment: It still doesn't make any sense. What do you mean by "how to deny permission for specific address"? The best answer I can think of is: `if(address != 'myStreet') return`

Comment: I am getting the employee location with latitude and longitude, but the employee should not put attendance when the latitude and longitude is within the office area